# SSIS - How to use variable as a source to compare with data in tables in fuzzy lookup?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

i have a requirement and this is my situation and idea. I have an excel file and i have extracted column header from it. For each column name it will be pass to SSIS as a variable into fuzzy lookup to determine the best matching column name in a table that available for it. My question is, can this be done? And how? Any suggestions, comments, or tips and tutorial are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Fuzzy lookup doesn't really work that way. You would at least have to provide your columns as a list of rows in a dataset in order for Fuzzy Lookup to pick one, and you won't be able to dynamically pick a column in SSIS let alone Fuzzy Lookup. Do you actually have a problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, what i'm trying to do is; I've a set of column headers that i extracted from excel. From the names of the column headers, i would like to map it to column names which is available in a table. The source column name from excel and the matching column name from the table will then be displayed in datagridview. This is basically what i'm trying to achieve. Any comments or ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by datagridview? Do you mean a grid in some kind of application or something in SSS? SSIS cannot dynamically map columns at runtime, They need to be fixed at design time. You could conceivably use a script transform to do what you want but it would be very complicated. If you're bringing an external application into the mix then you are just complicating things by using SSIS

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes. i am using winform. i noticed that things are getting more complicated now. i think maybe i will have to find another approach. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Agree with Nick's fine points. it sounds like the problem you are trying to solve is mapping dynamic column names from Excel to fixed column names in the database table. If you want to use SSIS, I'd propose building your winform to extract that Excel data into a CSV/text file with a fixed layout and then your SSIS package brings the data the rest of the way into the database

Comment: @billinkc i do want to map it dynamically. but i it's ok. i will try to find other alternative available. Thanks for the input guys!